# Android PlacePicker Search

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-maps-v2

I've created an activity that sends the user to pick a place using the PlacePicker.
However, there is no search feature in this.

Are there any flags i can set to tell the PlacePicker Intent to include a search bar?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396368/google-places-api-for-android-placepikcer-without-search-option