# Place Picker not showing search icon in Galaxy note5

Tags: android, google-places-api

Place Picker not showing search icon on top right, this is happening only in Galaxy note5:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1ujf11lh5mt12t/imgpsh_fullsize.jpeg?dl=0

My galaxy note5 have android 6.0.1

Any buddy knows why this is not showing only in note5 ?

Comment: This is problem the same problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313609/android-google-place-picker-does-not-display-search-box

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, I've had reports of this today too.  I assumed that it was related to the version of Play Services on the device, as the search option was only added to the place picker in December 2015: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_2015_-_v84.

However, having done some debugging, it looks to be phone related rather than Play Services related as I have two devices running the same version of Play Services (a Nexus tablet and a One Plus One) with the search option showing on the Tablet but not on the One Plus One.  Equally, these are both running a later version of Play Services than an old KitKat device I have which shows the icon fine.  Very odd.

**Resolved**: Ok, so my app had been compiled with Google Play Service 8.3.0.  Having now updated the version of Google Play Services to 8.4.0, I've had confirmation from users that the search icon is now showing correctly.

Comment: One more confusing case is the device that not showing icon in place picker, In same device we checked "Hangouts" app that uses same place picker that shows the icon fine, Its too odd.

Comment: Facing the same problem on htc device.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, so glad I'm not the only one. I have a Motorola MotoG3 with Marshmallow and i can't see the icon too. I tried with a Samsung Galaxy S3 mini with KitKat and the icon was showing, so I suppose is an issue related to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with the latest version of Google Play Services. Any devices that have updated to version 9.0.83 seem to be affected.

See my post regarding this issue: [Android PlacePicker no longer has Search icon after updating to Google Play Services 9.0.83](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266209/android-placepicker-no-longer-has-search-icon-after-updating-to-google-play-serv)

See these bug reports from the Google Maps API bug and feature website:
[Bug: Search Icon not visible in the latest play service update (Version:9.0.83)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9778&q=PlacePicker&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) ----- 
[Bug: Place Picker not showing search icon.](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9793&q=PlacePicker&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) -----
[PlacePicker search icon is gone after updating to Google Play Services 9.0.83](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9777&q=PlacePicker&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars)

Comment: Is this really issue with Google Play Service version 9.0.83 ? then how Hangouts app showing Place Picker with search icon ?

Comment: @kramk I can tell you from experience that Hangouts is special, it had the search icon way before it was made available to us for the the PlacePicker UI widget. This post will back up my claim: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396368/google-places-api-for-android-placepikcer-without-search-option). Read the history and specifically search for **hangouts**, note the dates of all the answers and comments.  I personally tested my app with 8.7.??? on a galaxy S7 edge then updated Play Services to 9.0.83 and viola - the search icon was gone.

Comment: Its OK about Hangouts app, may be they have inbuilt place picker for Hangouts But after your reply, i just searched the device that installed GPS version 9.0.83 then i found my Samsung Galaxy j5 that have gps ver 9.0.83 and showing search icon, So i can't say this issue is only with GPS version 9.0.83, It must be due to any invalid combination of Google Play Service version + Android version or any thing else....!

Comment: @kramk I think we're moving in the right direction! Since you have two devices running 9.0.83, please let me know the subversion. The subversion that I have is 440-121911109. Is the subversion different between the two devices?

Comment: i checked main version and sub version is same in both devices, that is 9.0.83 (236-121911109).